# Can navigate componentN(createAppContainer) from component outside componentN? It possible?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have Component App return (ComponentMain, ComponentA) with ComponentMain is a  createAppContainer. So, inside Component A i want to navigate ComponentMain. It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withNavigation` for outside stackNavigator components to use `navigation` as a prop.

Here is an example of how to use `withNavigation`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Button title="Back" onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.goBack() }} />;
  }
}

// withNavigation returns a component that wraps MyBackButton and passes in the
// navigation prop
export default withNavigation(ComponentA);
```

Comment: Hi bro! I'm try to using withNavigation but it don't work! error: 'Invariant Violation: withNavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator. The wrapped component is unable to get access to navigation from props or context'.

Comment: My code: 
==HomeComponent==
<code>
<View style = {{flex:1}}>
                <ActionBarComponent />                    
                <TitleComponent />    
                <App/> 
                <BottomBarComponent />                
            </View>
</code>

Comment: App is  AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppContainerAllStack);

Comment: Why don't you put ComponentA in a stack?

Comment: BottomBarComponent when click button then navigate in App

Comment: it's issue. I want navigate app from BottomBarComponent. It's possible?

Comment: put BottomBarComponent in your Stack

Comment: No BottomBarComponent outside my Stack! it's possible?

Comment: You have to put in in a stack or in a hierarchy of navigation view. That's the only way you can